# Total baking balance calculation (includes inactive bakers stake?)

Tags: baking, protocol, delegation

Does the total baking balance of the Tezos network (for example currently 76.9%) include the delegated XTZ to an inactive/sleeping/closed/defunct delegation services? At which point will these be excluded (if ever)? How does this affect the quorum cap for voting as this is at least 1-2% of the total XTZ in circulation?